# Is there a common best practice for rules generators?

Tags: design-patterns, content-management

I'm looking for examples of effective tools for generating and maintaining complex rules generators. Outlook's rules generator is nice – but doesn’t allow complex rules branching. Axure rules generator doesn't seem very convenient. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by rules here?

Comment: If it is Business Rules there one could always look at http://www.visual-rules.com/technology.html which I've tried in school.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for an expression builder/predicate editor? I have some examples in this post, #6 build an expression:
http://designingwebinterfaces.com/15-common-components

The example from Wufoo allows for *any* or *all* of the conditions to be applied. What we found in testing in numerous different industries is that most non-programmer people don't understand and/or on each condition and making the whole condition and, or the whole condition or was sufficient.